# How can I retrieve the UDID on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, udid

I was wondering if it was possible to find out the UDID of the user's iPhone. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but it is relevant to your question. Apple has is deprecating UDID access in iOS 5 http://techcrunch.com/2011/08/19/apple-ios-5-phasing-out-udid/

Comment: @Kye : then How AdHoc & Push notifications can be performed , i m sure apple will have a way around for this!

Comment: @Karthikeyan - Push notifications do not use a UDID

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Note: [Apple will no longer accept apps that access the UDID of a device starting May 1, 2013](http://www.macworld.com/article/2031573/apple-sets-may-1-deadline-for-udid-iphone-5-app-changes.html).

Instead, you must use the new methods `identifierForVendor` and `advertisingIdentifier` in iOS 6+ for accessing this.  See [related post here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/09/udid-apis-in-ios-6/) for more detail.

---

Old way (deprecated and will result in App Store rejection)

```
NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

As of iOS7, the `uniqueIdentifier` property is no longer available.

See the [`UIDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) reference.

Comment: Note that this has been deprecated in [iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

Comment: Another good note is if you still want something similar to UDID that was not mentioned above look into retrieving the device's unique MAC address.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: can you show me the solution get mac on ios 7, i just get mac address on ios 6. thanks

Answer (score 11):

Like some said, in iOS5 this has been deprecated:

```
NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

---

Apple now has 3 APIs to get a **UUID**(Universally Unique Identifier) of the device:

*Alternative 1 (NSUUID class):*

```
NSString *udid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

*Alternative 2 (UIDevice class):*

```
NSString *udid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

*Alternative 3 (ASIdentifierManager class, requieres AdSupport framework):*

```
NSUUID *UUID = [[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier];
NSString *udid = [UUID UUIDString];
```

---

But they are all alphanumeric, and a tipical device unique identifier is only digits. So thos 3 APIs are useless, and the old [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] still works in iOS6, but for how long?

If the "deprecated" warning bugs you, just add:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, UDIDs are alphanumeric.

Comment: 2nd alternative method is useful

Comment: Agree, with  Gajendra K Chauhan, Alternative 1 returns a different value each time is being called.

Answer (score 6):

In IOS5 and above, use this one to find UDID

```
NSString *uuidString = nil;
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
if (uuid) {
    uuidString = (__bridge NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    CFRelease(uuid);
}
NSLog(@"UDID: [%@]", uuidString);
```

Comment: it is very helpful for me very easy and it is used in ios5 or ios 6

Comment: Please note that this is a generated id, so subsequent calls to `CFUUIDCreate` will create different ids. Typical pattern is: try to load ID from `NSUSerDefaults`, if `nil` then generate it with the code above and store it in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: It's worth repeating: this is not the UDID of the device - it's a generated UUID, and a new one is generated at every call. If you want a unique identifier, this method is okay. If you want **the UDID of the device** this is useless.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth mentioning that the identifierForVendor is not unique for a device, it can and will eventually change.

Apple says this about [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor):

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the
>   same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned
>   for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for
>   apps on different devices regardless of vendor.
>
> If the value is nil, wait and get the value again later. This happens,
>   for example, after the device has been restarted but before the user
>   has unlocked the device.
>
> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. **The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can
>   also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app
>   on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores
>   the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle
>   situations where the identifier changes.**

But what is even worse, is that it seems that Apple is also removing the last resort of using the MAC address as a Unique identifyer, according to [this AVG Blog](http://blogs.avg.com/mobile-2/apple-ios-7-puts-unique-device-ids/).

So what to do now, if we want to uniquely identify devices - eg. for licensing, settings or other  purposes??

Answer (score 2):

> In IOS5 and above, use this one to find UDID
>
> NSString *uuidString = nil;
>
> CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
> ...

I think you are showing how to generate a unique identification number, not to get the unique id of a device.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment, but I would like to warn others.
In answer of DZenBot, all methods aren't giving the same results :

---

**Alternative 1** (NSUUID class):

```
NSString *udid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

**Alternative 2** (UIDevice class) (Available in iOS 6.0 and later):

```
NSString *udid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

---

*Alternative 1* generate a **random UUID** while *Alternative 2* give a **fixed UID** which won't change.

Comment: While identifierForVendor does return a fixed UID on subsequent calls, it does not uniquely identify a device. It will change if you delete all that vendors apps and reinstall them.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to do it like this

```
NSString *udid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
```

Comment: This has already been suggested by [DZenBot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12879212/1715579)'s and [Anc Ainu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16144111/1715579)'s answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [OpenUDID] lib https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Go to Xcode Window and select Devices or you can find it in Organizer.[image]

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood/organizerudid

Answer (score 0):

Remember UDID is deprecated in IOS 5. In iOS 7, Apple now always returns a fixed value when querying the MAC to specifically thwart the *MAC as base for an ID* scheme. So you now really should use [-[UIDevice identifierForVendor]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) or create a per-install UUID. Hope it will help for someone.