# Apple App store analytics - detect sale conversion from "LITE" to full version

Tags: ios, app-store

Do I need to implement custom logic in my code to track if the same user who purchased the "LITE" version went on to pay for the full version of the game? Or can I gather this information via iTunes Connect or some other non technical solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the UDID of the user's device (see: [How can I retrieve the UDID on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270200/how-can-i-retrieve-the-udid-on-ios)).

Then, you can send a hash (e.g., SHA256) of the UDID to your server whenever the lite version is launched. Whenever your full version is launched, you can send the same ping. Since the UDID is the same, the hash will be the same.

On your server, you can read from your database and see that hash ABCXYZ has launched both the lite and full versions of your games.