# How to get device IMEI number programmatically using swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to find device IMEI using swift code and any framework like (coreTelephone)?

Comment: This is a valid question. Why down-voting it?

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible in Swift or Objective-C. Apple does not allow developers to uniquely identify devices, protecting user privacy.

You can view this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927160/finding-imei-number-using-objective-c) for alternatives.