# Is there a way to get the Raw signal strength in iOS and if it's possible to get the IMEI on an iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, signal-strength

I'm new to iOS development, I need some advice or any workaround available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Neither of these things are possible on ios.

Comment: @zidniryi sorry mate, I don't have code yet. I'm still researching if those data are available on iOS

Comment: @Paulw11 do you have any resource material that can link to me so that I can read more about the topic? it will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No, because apple protect the users privacy : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39299245/how-to-get-device-imei-number-programmatically-using-swift

Answer (score 0):

No, Unable to get IMEI. Although IMEI cannot be obtained directly, you can create a unique key similar to IMEI.

Comment: Thank you @RateRebriduo, any idea if there's a way to get raw signal strength for iOS?