# How to get IMEI number of iPhone programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have used following code for getting the IMEI number of iPhone in objective-c:

```
NSString *imei = [[NetworkController sharedInstance] IMEI];
```

But I am getting this error, **Use of undeclared identifier** "NetworkController"
I have imported AFNetworking.h but I can not solve this error.
Can anybody help me for solving the issue?

Comment: Ok Thanks for my help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
You can get the UDID, but can not get the IMEI.Apple does not allow this.
```

Comment: As of iOS 5 you can no longer get the device UDID but you can get the vender ID which is something like an vendor specific device ID that will be a different value if the user re-installs the application and there is no other application from the same vendor.

Comment: Now a days, it is better to use UUID as a unique identifier for a user.

Comment: From IOS 5, Apple restricted to get the UDID. So its not possible. Wrong answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get IMEI number of iPhone. It is against security policy of Apple. Apple may reject your app.

Also, check this: [Finding IMEI number using Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927160/finding-imei-number-using-objective-c)