# Decoding IMEI to Serial Number

Tags: ios, iphone, algorithm, ipad

Is there an algorithm to obtain the serial number of "Apple" device, like iPhone or iPad, from IMEI of this device?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927160/finding-imei-number-using-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***There is no "algorithm"*** to obtain the serial number of an Apple device from the IMEI.

These numbers aren't releated to each other.

The IMEI (International Mobile Equipment Identity) is ***universal*** whereas a serial number is ***company specific***.

The company may be able to tell the serial number from the IMEI because they must be having the records. I'd suggest contacting Apple support.