# Steps for class attendance by using QRCODE

Tags: javascript, network-programming, webserver, qr-code, zxing

I have to create a project which is for **class attendance by using QRCODE** for my final year project.

My project was like:

> Students in the class will scan the QR CODE(using their own smartphone) that will be displayed by lecturers on the projector screen.

What I understand is, the Web server would get the secret ID from the smartphone IMEI and saves in the server database.

Actually, I don't know how to start because I don't understand the framework of the project.

Things that I know is:

> 1) Develop a system using PHP and XAMPP that acts as a server.
>
> 2) Develop an app using Ionic Framework
>
> 3) Beginner in Java network programming.

Can you guys please help me to make me clear **what should I do**? or help me understand the concept step by step. I really need your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know about Android, but this isn't possible on iOS.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927160/finding-imei-number-using-objective-c

Comment: I need to do for android. anyway thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand you correctly you want to achieve this:

1. User will open Ionic app and scan qr code.
2. After this Ionic will send lecture id and mobile device IMEI to your API.

This is possible and quite easy. You can this plugins:

**Ionic Native Barcode Scanner** (supports qr codes):

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner
```

**Ionic Native Uid** (supports IMEI numbers)

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/hygieiasoft/cordova-plugin-uid
npm install --save @ionic-native/uid
```

Then create function for scanning qr (and getting data from qr code) and sending data to your api (with data from qr code and device IMEI data). 
Something like this:

```
scanQrCode() {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((data) => {
        console.log('scanned data from qr ' + data.text);
        let imei = this.getImei();
        this.sendDataToApi(data.text, imei);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log('scanning error');
    })
}

getImei() {
    // handle permissions
    return this.uid.imei;
}
```

You can find more information about plugins here:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid/

Comment: btw, can you give me some idea how and where the lecturer wants to view the attendance? Is there any method that I can link it to Excel or Google Forms?

Comment: It depends how you want to design app architecture. The simplest solution will be storing all attendance in database. You can make REST service in your API and serve this in website.

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea about how to connect ionic database with web system? I don't know how to do the authentication process when the QR Code is scan for the attendance. Because ionic database that I knew to use is POSTMAN database and for web system I used phpmyadmin and XAMPP server. Is it any possibalitity to connect both of them?