# How to get IMEI no from device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I had add references `Plugin.DeviceInfo` in project and  used `CrossDevice.Device.DeviceId` for get IMEI no in code but it throws exception "The type initializer for `plugin.DeviceInfo.CrossDevice` threw an exception"`.
How to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(UniqueIdAndroid))]
namespace UniqueId.Droid
{
    public class UniqueIdAndroid : IDevice
    {
        public string GetIdentifier()
        {
            return Settings.Secure.GetString(Forms.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
string deviceIdentifier = DependencyService.Get<IDevice>().GetIdentifier();
```

Comment: I need same for iOS as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will get it myself.

Comment: We cannot get IMEI of an Apple device, Apple doesn't allow us. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927376/5941852)

Comment: Waht you import to use  Settings.Secure ?

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka use "using Android.Provider;"