# get device IMEI in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

how can i get device **IMEI** in flutter
i'm trying to get Unique Identifier using the following plugins:

```
uuid_type: ^0.7.0-dev
uuid: ^1.0.3
unique_identifier: ^0.0.3
flutter_udid: ^0.0.3
```

all of them geting ID but not the same IMEI ID for device

and when i try to use device_info plugin from this example [DeviceInfoPlugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/device_info)  
i get error :

**Multiple projects in this build have project**

Comment: Have you tried only have one of the dependencies at a time?
I assume you have imported the device_info as a dependency as specified at [their repository](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info#-installing-tab- "their repository") when trying to use the linked example.

Comment: "uuid" and "uuid_type" are NOT plugins to get the device identifier.

Those are dart libraries for the generation of UUIDs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: i need to get IMEI code

Comment: Even if something allowed you to retrieve a device's IMEI (or any other unique device identifier), using the IMEI to grant access is generally a bad idea (see, e.g., RFC 7254 sec. 8).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to get unique identifier ...

in Android: using `unique_identifier` to get IMEI

```
dev_dependencies:
  unique_identifier: ^0.0.3

  String  identifier =await UniqueIdentifier.serial;
```

in IOS: Apple no longer allows you to retrieve the IMEI or any other device identification,but you can generate UDID suing:

```
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = new DeviceInfoPlugin();
      var data = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo;
      identifier = data.identifierForVendor;
```

Comment: `  String  identifier =await UniqueIdentifier.serial;` This returns androidID not IMEI.

Comment: https://github.com/karantanwar/unique_identifier/blob/master/android/src/main/java/altercode/xyz/uniqueidentifier/UniqueIdentifierPlugin.java#L27

Comment: Is there a modern solution available? `unique_identifier` doesn't work anymore :/

Answer (score 8):

Android no longer allows you to access the IMEI or any other device identifier starting from **android 10**. Third party apps can not use IMEI & the serial number of a phone and other non-resettable device identifiers. So, **now you can't access**:

`getSerial()`,

`getImei()`,

`getDeviceId()`,

`getSimSerialNumber()`,

```
getSubscriberId()
```

You have to use another unique identifier for this like Android ID

Please refer: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/data-identifiers#device-ids

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the device serial number.

The following plugin did the trick for me:

[android_multiple_identifier](https://pub.dev/packages/android_multiple_identifier)

Modify pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
    android_multiple_identifier: ^1.0.3
```

Add the permission to AndroidManifest.xml:

Location -> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.my_app_name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Create a class and access the information:

```
import 'package:android_multiple_identifier/android_multiple_identifier.dart';

class DeviceInfo {

    Future<String> getDeviceSerialNumber() async {
        // Ask user permission
        await AndroidMultipleIdentifier.requestPermission();
        // Get device information async
        Map idMap = await AndroidMultipleIdentifier.idMap;

        String imei = idMap["imei"];
        String serial = idMap["serial"];
        String androidID = idMap["androidId"];

        return imei;
      }
}
```

Comment: doesn't support null safety

Comment: Dart 3 incompatible

Answer (score 1):

Apple no longer allows you to retreive the IMEI or any other device identificator:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927376/2461957

Answer (score 0):

I just meet the same question, and tried pakage `platform_device_id`, and found the device id changed when I changed the internet