# Get IMEI / serial number on Android Devices

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a problem. I want to get the `IMEI` and or `serial number` of an Android device with the framework flutter.
For all solutions what I found, there were a *fake* `IMEI` / `serial number` or there were empty.

So what is the best option to get the *real* `IMEI` / `serial number` of an Android device ? The permission for `phone.status` `isGranted`. There could be also a possible solution to write *real* Android source code in Kotline or Java to use this `IMEI` / `serial number`.

```dart
await Permission.phone.request();
var statusPhone = await Permission.phone.status;
if (statusPhone.isGranted) {
...
}
```

```dart
dependencies:
  device_info: ^2.0.0
```

```dart
import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';

...

void getDeviceData() async {
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;

  String imei = androidInfo.androidId; // IMEI-Nummer
  String serialNumber = androidInfo.serial; // Seriennummer

  print('IMEI: $imei');
  print('Serial Number: $serialNumber');
}
```

I also tried:

- [get device IMEI in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030779/get-device-imei-in-flutter) `unique_identifier`
- https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus `device_info_plus`

---

**EDIT**

> Starting from Android 10, access to such sensitive device identifiers
> is restricted for privacy and security reasons. Google Play Store
> policies also enforce these restrictions.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Is it possible at all to get such sensetive information as e.g. `IMEI`? It is a private app and not for Google Play Store use.

Comment: From your linked question "get device IMEI in flutter", there's also an answer about Android >= 10, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64657600/1741542