How to get IMEI/Serial Number from device
I am trying to get the IMEI/Serial Number from the device to compare it to our MDM records for an internal application but I am having an issue. It keeps telling me insufficient permissions but I added the permissions to my Manifest file. I am not sure if there is additional requirements that I am missing or its not possible. I used both the device_info_plus and the device_imei package.

Added Permissions to Manifest.
Added TestDPC


Normal apps cannot get these values

I guess starting from android 10, the android no longer allows to access IMEI, and for ios read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927376/14071053  so you need to find something else to work with like androidId or serial no. etc.

@tyczj is there a way to "make it a non normal" app

You need to have your app signed with the OS or have a rooted device

The vendors are deliberately making this harder and harder to get, partially because of EU privacy, but also because it makes it harder for a customer to buy a new phone.  And the vendors want to sell new phones.
